# how to get set of input boxes values using getElemntById?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of input boxes to add names and designaions.and iwant to print those in a `<p>` tag when user click print button. how to proceed.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputRegNo" >Name & Designation<span style="color:#c0392b;padding-left:5px;">*</span></label>
    <div class="form-group">
          <input required  type="text" name="fname[]"  class="fname" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML = this.value" placeholder="Name" />
           <input required  type="text" name="lname[]" placeholder="Designation" />
    </div>                    
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputRegNo" ></label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="fname[]" placeholder="Name" class="fname" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML = this.value" />
        <input  type="text" name="lname[]" placeholder="Designation" />
    </div>                  
</div>
```

## print

```
<div>
    <label>Name & Designation</label>
    <p id="refa5"> - </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a question and answer site...what is the question?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to print all these input boxes values inside <p> tag which shown in question. currently it prints only last inputbox value only

Comment: because you overwrite the innerHTML of the same element each key stroke

Comment: Also, correct me if I am wrong, but I think that you should not use this `this.value` in your on click argument.

Answer (score 0):

its looks you are new in javascript.. it's simple give the `name` to all the input field like

```
<input type="text/checkbox" name="txtName">
```

and in javascript you can access this field value by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var name  = document.getElementsByName("txtName");
</script>
```

if you wish to print the element on button click simply specify their click event on javascript like

```
function onClick() {

alert("helo from click function");
}
```

and then on button ..

```
<input type="button" onclick="onClick()">
```

Answer (score -1):

w3schools is a great resource for this. Here is some example code on how to do this :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<input id="inputID"></input>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var inputID = document.getElementById("inputID").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputID;
}
</script>
```

What the code above does is it takes the `value` of an input, then it sets the `innerHTML` of a `<p>` element to it. You can obviously do this with other things like `<h1>` elements as well.

Comment: this won't produce any different results than what OP already is doing

Comment: Ok, that is true. But I am answering the question they asked.

Comment: and if it is of any consideration, my code does look a lot better.

Comment: How so when it doesn't produce expected results?

Comment: And what would those results be?